# 'We'll stop supporting this browser soon." this warning appears on top of the youtube.com page when it is accessed via WKWebview in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, wkwebview

In my ios app I am using WKWebview to browse youtube videos and save it for later use. Recently I noticed mentioned above warning message. I tried it on SFSafariViewController, it is not customizable.

Thanks.

Comment: In which iOS version, did you get this warning?

Comment: yes, on ios 13.3. the warning is not there in SFSafariViewController.